# No such file or directory but file is exists

Tags: bash

I'm newb in bash. I try to start perl script from bash script here is part of script:

```
PERL_HOME=/u/.../app/perl; export PERL_HOME;
PERL=$PERL_HOME/bin/perl; export PERL;
$PERL script.pl
```

I have ***No such file or directory*** */u/.../app/perl/bin/perl* but file exists. When I do `echo $PERL` I get path to perl like */u/app/../perl/bin/perl* but when I do `` echo `$PERL` ``  ***No such file or directory***

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l $PERL`?

Comment: The same like `ls -l ` without $PERL

`drwxr-xr-x. 8 user user  Script
-rwxr-x---. 1 user usert script-log.sh
-rwxrwxr--. 1 user user  script.pl
-rwxr-x---. 1 user user  script.sh
drwxr-xr-x. 4 user user lib`

Comment: sounds like your `$PERL` is empty.

Comment: `bash -x /your/script [args]...` and see whats happening.

Comment: I think the back ticks in the second echo command may be part of the problem. For example, I can `echo $PATH` to find its directory, but the directory in `echo \`$PATH\`` is not recognized. It's probably not the right syntax for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @pynexj I have
'+ PERL_HOME=/u/app/../app/perl`
`+ export PERL_HOME`
`+ PERL=/u/app/../app/perl/bin/perl`
`+ export PERL`
and then where I need to start script.pl
` /u/app/../app/perl/bin/perl script.pl /u/app/../ some_IP /u/app/.../tmp /u/app/.../etc/app/app/app.conf utf8 HOST_NAME '**UNDEF**'
script.sh: line 92: /u/app/../perl/bin/perl: No such file or directory`
I have some input arguments in script.pl may be it's a problem?

Comment: @Duxa : What are the three dots `...`  doing in your definition of `PERL_HOME`? Then, you say you posted only _part of the bash script_. Exctract only the relevant portion into a new bash script, and run it. Then copy and paste here the exact output you get **verbatim**, and also paste the complete test script you were running, and how exactly you were calling it. Also, do a `ls -l "$PERL"` in your example and show us the result.

Comment: I've started use another perl and script.pl works